# Finding $x$-intercepts of $4x^2-3y^2+2xy-12=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got to find the x-intercepts of $4x^2-3y^2+2xy-12 = 0$.
I've tried isolating one variable and it just doesn't work out. Wolfram|Alpha says the answer is $√3$.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Put $y=0$, answers are immediate. By the way there are two of them.

Comment: It helps a lot to think about what we are looking for before starting to calculate. The expression looks pretty nice as it stands.

Answer (score 6):

The x-intercept by definition is when $y=0$. Putting this into the equation we get

$4x^{2}-12=0$.

So $x^{2}=3$. Thus, $x=\pm\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: You mean $x=\pm\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: My mistake, I will correct that. Thank you for your edit.